Better Solidify Options
Are there any options out there for solidifying a model for 3D printing than the built-in Solidify modifier? For example, here is what will be the rim of the cockpit tub on a spacecraft model:

You can very clearly see where the interior faces are poking through. It's hard to believe that after so many versions, Blender STILL hasn't improved the modifier so as to eliminate these sorts of issues.
I'm starting to get frustrated, here, because this is proving a major holdup to being able to complete the model.
